# Slow USB transfer speeds

Tags: 13.04, usb, external-hdd

I am experiencing very slow USB transfer speeds when trying to backup files to a USB HDD. I am not entirely sure when the problem 1st occured but there was definitely a period using 12.04 where transfer speeds were fine and then they dropped to kbs/s and backups became impossible. It might well have coincided with a software update but at the time I thought maybe the USB HDD was at fault and didn't make a note of any software changes.

I have since used other USB HDDs and see the same issue. I have also upgraded to 13.04 and the problem remains.

The details of my machine are as follows:

lscpi:

> 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor
>   Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
>
> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation
>   Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
>
> 00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200
>   Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
>
> 00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset
>   Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
>
> 00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset
>   Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
>
> 00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset
>   Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
>
> 00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset
>   Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)
>
> 00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset
>   Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b5)
>
> 00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset
>   Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
>
> 00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC
>   Controller (rev 05)
>
> 00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series
>   Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
>
> 00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family
>   SMBus Controller (rev 05)
>
> 05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
>   RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
>
> 06:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285
>   Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)

lsusb:

> Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching
>   Hub
>
> Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching
>   Hub
>
> Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>
> Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>
> Bus 001 Device 005: ID 26bd:9917
>
> Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Card
>   reader
>
> Bus 002 Device 005: ID 046d:c52e Logitech, Inc.
>
> Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b277 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd
>
> Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0489:e00d Foxconn / Hon Hai Broadcom Bluetooth
>   2.1 Device

dmesg:

> [  434.552616] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using
>   ehci-pci
>
> [  435.950539] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=26bd,
>   idProduct=9917
>
> [  435.950555] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2,
>   SerialNumber=3
>
> [  435.950563] usb 1-1.2: Product: Portable SSD
>
> [  435.950570] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Integral
>
> [  435.950575] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 07073404D5442A05
>
> [  436.120805] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
>
> [  436.121280] scsi7 : usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
>
> [  436.121562] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
>
> [  436.121569] USB Mass Storage support registered.
>
> [  437.448442] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Integral Portable SSD
>   PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
>
> [  437.450971] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
>
> [  437.947534] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] 246546432 512-byte logical blocks:
>   (126 GB/117 GiB)
>
> [  438.247077] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
>
> [  438.247085] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 45 00 00 00
>
> [  438.546644] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache:
>   enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
>
> [  440.643704]  sdc: sdc1
>
> [  442.341191] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
>
> [  450.103616] systemd-hostnamed[3254]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not
>   installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable.
>   Please install nss-myhostname!

I have noticed that one of my USB sockets on the laptop seems to come up as usb 1-1.2 in dmesg whereas the others come up as 2-1.2. Potentially this is the source of the problem , i.e. one USB is USB 1 whereas the rest are USB 2? Subjectively, luckybackup does seem to run a lot quicker when I plug the USB HDD in any othe USB port than the one that dmesg is reporting as 1-1.2

Comment: For the casual reader ending up here: GUI tool `sudo usbview` comes in handy when inspecting USB connections. Also, read related question [How do I get better USB transfer speeds in (X)ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/questions/203538/how-do-i-get-better-usb-transfer-speeds-in-xubuntu/1437610)