# Extremely slow USB transfer speed

Tags: usb

I'm getting extremely slow USB transfer speeds with Ubuntu 14.04. I have a new USB 3.0 Stick and I'm getting transfer rates of about 0.5 Mb/s. I discovered through this site that this is a common issue with ubuntu users and tried some of the suggestions (like deactivating the "sync" option when mounting) but none of them seemed to help. I'm still asking this question because the solutions (if there were any) to the other questions (e.g. [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156640/why-is-my-usb-data-transfer-so-slow?rq=1%22this%20question%22) or [that question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299430/slow-usb-transfer-speeds?rq=1))  seemed very specific to me, so maybe there is still hope. As I'm a total noob, I have no idea what kind of information might be helpful to you, so please tell me what you need to know.

Not sure if this is relevant, but the data I wanted to copy originated from a Win7-system.

Edit: As requested, the output of lsusb

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 1e7d:2c2e ROCCAT 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05c8:0361 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The USB Stick is a PNY 64 GB USB 3.0

Comment: The output of `lsusb` would be a good start, as well as the make and model of the USB stick. Also, what "other questions"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so after I rebooted my computer twice today because of some software updates, it suddenly works (I get like 50 Mb/s).